# How do I add an associative array to a variable from an external ini file?

Tags: bash, array

I'm modifying a simple script to add function and learn more about how to write bash scripts. Currently, the script creates associative arrays using a function:

```
declare -A site theme
add_site() {
    local shortcut=$1
    site[$shortcut]=$2
    theme[$shortcut]=$3
}
add_site x1 example1.com alpha
add_site x2 example2.com beta
```

Now I'd like it to read an ini file for the variables. However, the documentation I've come across all instruct how to source the file, but only uses single arrays for examples. How do I create the arrays using a data file that looks like the following to make an associative array:

```
[site1]
shortcut=x1
site=example1.com
theme=alpha

[site2]
shortcut=x2
site=example2.com
theme=beta
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A site=() theme=()

add_site() {
    local shortcut=$1
    site[$shortcut]=$2
    theme[$shortcut]=$3
}

while IFS= read -r line; do
    case "$line" in
    shortcut=*)
        # IFS== read -r __ shortcut <<< "$line"
        _shortcut=${line#*=}
        ;;
    site=*)
        # IFS== read -r __ site <<< "$line"
        _site=${line#*=}
        ;;
    theme=*)
        # IFS== read -r __ theme <<< "$line"
        _theme=${line#*=}
        add_site "$_shortcut" "$_site" "$_theme"
        ;;
    esac
done < file.ini
```

Test output with added `echo "$@"` on function:

```
x1 example1.com alpha
x2 example2.com beta
```

Comment: When I test the output I only get the first set of variables. 
Using for loop to iterate I can see a zero value for the second key in the site array.

Comment: @user1074170 I used local names same to the array variable names sorry. I made an update.

Comment: I don't see the zero value key anymore but it seems to be only storing the first set of values.

Comment: @user1074170 It works well on my test. Can you show debug output? (`bash -x script.sh`)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/wxMFc3xQ looks like its not firing the add_site function the second time.

Comment: @user1074170 The last line of your ini file is not terminated with a newline. Is that the default form of the file?

Comment: No it's not the default, but that worked! Thanks a heap.